# Large Database Error - Upgrading EE 1.x to 2.9.2

Tags: database, upgrade, database-error

I’m trying to upgrade an installation of EE 1.6.8 to 2.9.2 and have come unstuck on the “Database too large” error in the upgrade wizard.

Specifically:

```
The following error occurred:
An unexpected error occurred while performing the update

Your database is too large to perform this part of the upgrade via a web request. Please contact your system administrator and have them run the script located at: 

/Work/MYWEBSITE/Site Upgrade 2014/ee-localserver-01/system/expressionengine/cache/installer/update.sh 

Then access this page again.
```

I have run the update shell script but it finishes within seconds and outputs this result:

```
Last login: Thu Nov 20 12:48:27 on ttys000
You have mail.
/Work/MY-SITE-REDACTED\ MY-SITE-REDACTED/Site\ Upgrade\ 2014/ee-localserver-01/system/expressionengine/cache/installer/update.command ; exit;
MY-MAC-NAME:~ liam$ /Work/MY-SITE-REDACTED\ MY-SITE-REDACTED/Site\ Upgrade\ 2014/ee-localserver-01/system/expressionengine/cache/installer/update.command ; exit;
Starting Large Database Conversion
UTF-8 Conversion (Step 1: Dumping database with current charset)
/Work/MY-SITE-REDACTED/Site Upgrade 2014/ee-localserver-01/system/expressionengine/cache/installer/update.command: line 10: mysqldump: command not found
UTF-8 Conversion (Step 2: Importing database with UTF-8 charset)
/Work/MY-SITE-REDACTED/Site Upgrade 2014/ee-localserver-01/system/expressionengine/cache/installer/update.command: line 17: mysql: command not found
UTF-8 Conversion (Step 3: Removing database dump)
DST Conversion (Step 1: Reading queries)
DST Conversion (Step 2: Writing temporary SQL file)
DST Conversion (Step 3: Importing temp file, this may take several minutes)
/Work/MY-SITE-REDACTED/Site Upgrade 2014/ee-localserver-01/system/expressionengine/cache/installer/update.command: line 291: mysql: command not found
DST Conversion (Step 4: Removing temp file)
Large Database Conversion Completed: Please return to the browser to finish your upgrade.
logout

[Process completed]
```

Going back to the upgrade wizard in the browser just puts me back in to the same error loop.

Any help would be seriously appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have access to mysql or mysqldump from the command line (or it's not installed on your machine). On a side note, I would be thoroughly amazed if you can upgrade from a 1.x installation all the way to the latest setup.

Comment: Thanks jpea. I don't know why it's failing either. I'm running Mamp Pro and Sequel Pro and can view and edit the database with no problem.

Comment: As for the upgrade process I've already upgraded 2 installations of EE 1.6.8 to EE 2.9.2 this week without any major issues. This site was to be my third upgrade but it also has the largest database ad that's where I ran into these problems. I think my only option is to try and reduce the size of the database so that I don't run into the command line process. Although I can't seem to find the maximum database size that triggers this behaviour in the EE upgrade process.

Comment: The error said it couldn't find mysqldump so it seems like you have to specify where mysqldump sits in your mamp install. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268789/add-mysqldump-to-mamp-mysql-w-apache-php-on-macos-x - a normal lamp install would have an alias from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions jpea. In the end I did't solve the issue directly I just ended up reducing the database size by giving it a well overdue hose down and removing lots of crud.

Comment: And it updated easily after that? If so, that gives me hope for another update I have coming up :)

Comment: Well I wouldn't say it was easy but I developed a process over the previous 2 site upgrades from EE 1.x to EE 2.9.2 that I applied. Backup every step and be very slow and methodical and it should be OK.